# Unable to use OAuthConsumer (SecKeychainItemRef undeclared) - iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, oauth

I'm trying to use the OAuthConsumer framework (http://code.google.com/p/oauthconsumer/) but when I try building it among my iPhone app, xCode tells me that SecKeychainItemRef is undeclared. I previously added the Security framework to my target but it doesn't fix my problem.

What should I do to fix that?

Thanks!

Martin

Comment: Please show us the exact error you're getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I manage to get rid of the error using this : http://code.google.com/p/oauthconsumer-iphone/

Cheers!